# Hide Delete button based on User permission in Django Crispy Form

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

How can I check user permissions within a Django crispy form? Basically I would like to hide Delete button for users who have no delete permission.

Please help. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by passing user object to **init** method of Model form.

Now it looks something like below

```
    def __init__(self,**user**, *args, **kwargs):
         super(B2BInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.helper = FormHelper()

         ...

         print "Checking Permission :", user.get_all_permissions()

         if **user**.has_perm('can.delete_something') :
             self.helper.add_input(Submit('delete', ' Delete '))
```

Its not just user object, we can pass any object to form and use it to render the form dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Layout Docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#layouts).

Check your user's permissions in the view and configure the `Layout` appropriately.

(That's it)

Comment: Thanks for the response.